# Word Press:Making the header image appear on one page

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm on Word Press in the function.php file and I'm trying to figure out how to make the header img appear one just the home page. I found the area in the code where it was and are trying to add an if statement with a condition is appears on that page only.

```
if(is_front_page()){
  require get_template_directory() . '/inc/custom-header.php';
}
```

Comment: Scratch that. Have you tried is_page(PAGE_ID)?

Comment: Why on functions.php? is this part of a function? You want it as a background image or a image? If it's a image why are you including a php file? Please describe better what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a child theme, `get_template_directory()` will return the path of the parent theme. Source: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory

So, if you didn't specify a page for your front page (ie. your front page is basically the blog), `is_home()` should work properly, otherwise use `is_front_page()`.

In case your file (custom-header.php) is in the proper folder, this should do the trick:

```
if (is_front_page()) { // or is_home(), read above
    include_once(get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/inc/custom-header.php');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use [is_home()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home)

```
if(is_home()){
  require get_template_directory() . '/inc/custom-header.php';
}
```

Comment: Should have said originally that is_home() was the first condition i tried. thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you make a different template for the homepage?

Comment: Take a look here: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/template-for-front-page-only.

Comment: What I did: create a different php file. Something like home.php and in it add a header /* Template Name: My HomePage */ as a php comment. Next assign the template to the static homepage.